# Verifying types in a python function (including types from the typing module)

Tags: python, function, types, typing

I am trying to create a function in python that can be used in other functions to verify that arguments passed into the function are of the correct type(s)

It works for standard python types, e.g. 'str', 'int', etc.,
but I want it to be able to check more complex types, such as a list containing strings and integers (typing.List[int, str]) or an iterable object (typing.Iterable)

Below is an example of what it should be able to do

```
def some_function(arg1: int, arg2: List[int, str]):

    # call the check_types function to check argument types
    check_types(arg1, int, argname="arg1", funcname="some_function")
    check_types(arg2, typing.List[int,str], argname="arg2", funcname="some_function")


some_function(1, 3)
# This should raise an error like:
# TypeError: 'arg2' to 'some_function' must be type 'typing.List[int, str]', not 'int'
```

Comment: A general purpose algorithm for this is going to be way outside the scope of a Q&A here. There's a reason tools like Mypy exist, and why they have [quite a bit of code in them](https://github.com/python/mypy).

Comment: Yeah, incorporating type checking in runtime is proving to be quite difficult

Comment: The **entire point** of type checking is that it happens before runtime. If you want to find out, at runtime, whether a type was incorrect, that is what `except TypeError:` is for.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, at least in a general way, because while you can get the type annotations of the function's parameters, the objects that your function receives at runtime as arguments don't have type annotations attached to them.

A function's types and their parameters can be inspected via its `__annotations__` property:

```
>>> def foo(x: list[int]) -> None:
...     print(sum(x))
...
>>> foo.__annotations__
{'x': list[int], 'return': None}
>>> foo.__annotations__['x'].__args__
(<class 'int'>,)
```

but an actual list that is referenced by a variable that was annotated as `list[int]` has no such property that you can get the `int` type parameter from:

```
>>> a: list[int] = []
>>> dir(a)
['__add__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
>>> type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

A static typechecking tool (e.g. `mypy`) can see the annotation at the point where `a` is declared, and it can use that to validate that `foo(a)` is a valid function call, but runtime logic inside `foo` can't do that because the annotation isn't bound to the object at runtime.

You can of course hack around it with something like `isinstance(a, list) and all(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)` but it's hard to generalize this, and it doesn't actually provide a guarantee that `a` has the annotation you expect (an empty list at runtime is effectively a `list[Any]`, even though in a static typechecking context the type of objects you can add to it is constrained by its type annotation).

The simple solution is to use `mypy` (or similar) statically rather than trying to enforce type annotations at runtime -- or make a best effort at runtime and accept that you'll miss a lot of cases that static type checking would have caught.